# What is the prediction formula used by SARIMAX module to predict one step ahead?

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I estimated an ARIMA model with SARIMAX and also made a prediction. However, I am trying to replicate that prediction but do not get the same result.
The model that I estimated is an `ARIMA(1,0,1)` model without seasonality and with 1 external regressor.

I thought the formula to predict this one period ahead (using estimated coefficients) was:

```
y_(t+1)= y(t)*phi_1 + e_t*theta_1 + x_t * beta_1
```

Where `phi_1` is the AR(1) coefficient, `theta_1` the MA(1) coefficient and `beta_1` the coefficient of the external regressor. `y_t` is the dependent variable and `x_t` the external variable regressor. `e_t` is the error term at time t.

Am I not using the correct formula? Which formula does SARIMAX use?

Read user guide, searched on Google

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Statsmodels implements SARIMAX as "regression with SARIMA" errors (see the documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html)). This answer explains the differences in more detail: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394593/manually-calculate-sarimax-forecast/399103#399103